# What does =* mean? (Winsock - C++)

Tags: c++, winsock, operator-keyword

I was learning about Winsock and was looking at code from the page : 
[Winsock Tutorial 1](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_1.shtm).

There is a line in the program which included the operator =*. Can anyone please tell me what this is? I do know a *= b is equivalent to a = a * b. And I read on stackoverflow that =+ is the obsolete form of +=. So I tried interchanging the * and = making it *=, but the compiler gave me an error. I would really appreciate it if someone tells me what this line of code means :

```
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=*((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
```

Comment: It's an assignment operator with no whitespace between it and the dereference operator.

Comment: This is why sane programmers put spaces around operators like `=`.

Comment: +1 for making me chuckle. -1 because I'm only joking about the +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means de-reference something and assign it to the LHS.

```
SomeType LHS;
SomeType* Something = ....;
LHS = *(Something);
```

See [dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

Comment: O I did know that LOL. It means "content of" right? Like when we de-reference pointers. But what are we doing over here? Typecasting it to be a pointer and then de-referencing it? What good will that do?

Comment: @ShahidKhaliq `host->h_addr` is probably a pointer to something, so it is doing a C-syle cast to `unsigned long*`, then dereferencing it to set the value of `SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr`.

Comment: Okay. I kinda get it now. Thanks a million! It looked confusing without the space between = and *.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `=*` existed in nascent versions of C language (as the original form of `*=` operator).

In C++ there's no such operator. `=*` is nothing else than `=` (assignment operator) followed by unary `*` (dereference operator). You can look up the meaning of `=` and unary `*` in your favorite C++ book.